# Constructor Injection on Silex Controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, silex

I am using silex form my project, I added yml routing , In my controller action I don't want pass `Silex\Application` on every time. I just want to inject Application through the constructor, I tried like this,

```
protected $_app;  

function __construct(Application $app) {      
    $this->_app =   $app;
}
```

getting error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Smart\Controllers\IndexController::__construct() must be an instance of Silex\Application, none given

how can I resolve this? or How can I achieve a safe injection for do the same?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`ServiceControllerServiceProvider`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html), so you can use controllers as services. And then you can inject the application:

```
$app = new \Silex\Application();
$app['controller.index'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new \Smart\Controllers\IndexController($app);
};

$app->get('/', "controller.index:indexAction");
```

Comment: am using yml routing provide, then how can I inject like this..?

Comment: @Nisam only the last line is your routing config. The other lines are services configuration, you should do that in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For injecting $app in constructor baseController, i created a decorator controllerResolver of symfony :

Overload method createController in a DecoratorControllerResolverSymfony extends Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolve

```
protected function createController($controller)
    {
        if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find controller "%s".', $controller));
        }
        list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $class));
        }
        return array(new $class($this->app), $method);
    }
```

```
$app['resolver'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {

            //test
            if(isset($app['logger'])){
                $logger = $app['logger'];
            }else{
                $logger = null;
            }

            $defaultResolver = new ControllerResolver($logger);

            return new DecoratorControllerResolverSymfony($defaultResolver, $app, $logger);
        });
```

then go to created AbsractController with a constructor parameter $app

for more detail : https://github.com/nagi88/silex-skeleton-mvc-module

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply put it when you call your controllers, and pass it as argument like this:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->mount('/test', new Test\TestController($app));
```

Comment: This is not working, check @wouter-j 's answer for the recommended way